# "So long as" vs. "as long as"

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions, formality, writing-style, so-vs-as

Which phrase is more formal — "so long as" or "as long as"?

Example:

> - So long as Google Voice allows free long distance in North America, I will use it.
> - As long as Google Voice allows free long distance in North America, I will use it.

I'm leaning toward 'as long as' but I have no justification.

Comment: I seem to recall reading, years ago, in a very old edition of *Word Power Made Easy*, [Norman Lewis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Lewis_%28grammarian%29) prescribing that *so long as* is the high fallutin' distinguished usage, and *as long as* is junk used by phillistines. :)

Comment: How odd, I would say the opposite. As long as is kosher and so long as is not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know that the distinction between these two is formality. I think that "so long as" indicates a logical predication, and "as long as" indicates a specific time interval.  Take your two examples.

- So long as Google Voice allows free long distance in North America, I will use it.

I think this could be paraphrased as

- My use of Google Voice is conditional upon free long distance calls in North America.

Your second example was

- As long as Google Voice allows free long distance in North America, I will use it.

This could be paraphrased as

- For the duration of time that Google Voice allows free long distance in North America, I will be using it.

Thinking about it, I think that both "so long as" and "as long as" are used for the conditional reading, but only "as long as" can be used for the duration reading.

Comment: I've always thought of "so long as" as being a little more casual, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Well, I'm +1 here, but I think that "so long as" **can** be used for the duration reading, so long as you assume that there is the word "For" implied at the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

Both the phrases mean *during the whole time that*.

The *Corpus of Contemporary American English* reports that the most used phrase is *as long as*.
*as long as* is used more in magazines and newspapers than in academic texts; *so long as* is used more in academic texts than magazines and newspapers.

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago I was taught that *so* is used within the scope of a negative and *as* within the scope of a positive or neutral context. Thus:

- I won't go so long as Billy is going to be there.
- I'm staying home as long as nobody else is going either.

I have never found authority for this distinction, and it may be someone's idiosyncratic notion. In my editing, I continue to make the distinction because it causes no harm and the justification for it may pop up unexpectedly.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you should use "as long as," since you are talking about a duration of time. More here:

http://snarkygrammarguide.blogspot.com/search/label/as%20long%20as%20vs.%20so%20long%20as

Comment: Oh come on, surely you can excerpt enough from that link for this to be a useful answer (especially when it seems to be your own blog!)

Comment: Your very own blog suggests that he can use either phrase. It is not clear whether he is measuring a duration of time ("I'll use it for this long"), or giving a condition ("I'll use it if it is available"). Personally, I interpret it as a condition. To interpret it as a duration of time implies that he'll use it non-stop for that long. Still, when I visited your blog, I found myself agreeing with you. Fortunately, we have no police from whom we must fear English grammar enforcement; but I like to discover and know the rules, and I think this one is sticky, so I appreciate your explanation.