# So long as they aren't answering

Tags: phrases, comparisons, so-vs-as

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“So long as” vs. “as long as”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2025/so-long-as-vs-as-long-as)

> It is no problem so long as they aren't answering.

I think that's not a correct phrase, but I can't find out how to correct it.

Comment: There's nothing grammatically wrong with it at all. Whether it would be appropriate depends on the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["So long as"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so%20long%20as) is an entirely valid expression.

Answer (score 2):

"It is no problem as long as they aren't answering" is a more direct comparison.